# Возвращение строк через SELECT но без SELECT..INTO

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsql-developer

Есть код, по результатам которого мне нужно достать сумму из одной таблицы в другую.
Чтобы её достать я установил условия совпадения номеров записей между таблицами(есть связанные и совпадающие записи)

```
create or replace function F_TESTSUM
(
nRN NUMBER
) 
RETURN NUMBER
AS
  INRN NUMBER;
  RES PKG_STD.tSTRING;
BEGIN
  INRN:=nRN;
  BEGIN 
     SELECT CLPG.SUMM ---выбираем сумму из таблицы
       INTO RES
       FROM  CLNPOSTSGS CLPG, --таблица откуда берётся сумма
       GRSALARY GRSL, --- таблица, откуда беру вид оплаты суммы
       CLNPSDEP CLNDPG,---таблица откуда беру даты проверки
       CLNPOSTS CLPN --- таблица,по которой начинаю сравнивать номера записей для остальных таблиц
       WHERE 
       CLPG.PRN = INRN
       AND CLPG.PRN=CLPN.RN -- Записи равны между двумя таблицами
       AND CLPN.RN=CLNDPG.POSTRN -- Записи равны между двумя таблицами     
       AND CLPG.GRSALARY = GRSL.RN -- Совпадение кода 'оклад' между двумя таблицами
       AND CLNDPG.DO_ACT_FROM<=SYSDATE AND (CLNDPG.DO_ACT_TO>=SYSDATE OR CLNDPG.DO_ACT_TO IS NULL)
       AND GRSL.CODE = 'оклад'; -- Само условия вида суммы 'оклад'
  END;
  RETURN RES;
END F_TESTSUM;
```

Но здесь вопрос не в условиях, а в том, что как только начинаю работать, то вылетает исключение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я почитал о данной проблеме, исключение вылетает при использовании `SELECT INTO`с учётом возвращения не одной строки, а нескольких строк.

Я отдельно проверил `SELECT` и у меня возвращается много строк.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда получается `SELECT INTO` не подходит, как надо мне решить мою проблему?

Comment: А кокая из многих строк вам нужна, вы же собираетесь вернуть __только одну__?

Comment: @0xdb я хочу получить следующий результат
То есть нахожу запись(строку) с Summ , согласно условиям в WHERE и загружаю её в другую таблицу. Но эта Summ загрузится только лишь при условиях указанных в WHERE/

Comment: Хорошо, и что у вас не получается? Ещё раз внимательно прочтите мой комментерий выше, вы на него так и не ответили.